# Meaning of "He had the over/under at 25” minutes."

Tags: meaning-in-context

What did the President mean, when he said this:

“Enough talk,” Mr. Obama said. “President Bush was timing me. He had the over/under at 25” minutes. (http://www.nytimes.com/2016/09/26/us/politics/for-some-bush-obama-rapport-recalls-a-lost-virtue-political-civility.html The last sentence.)

Did Bush bet on him talking longer or shorter?

Comment: I'm a native British English speaker, and this conveys absolutely nothing to me. From the context, I think it must mean that Bush gave him a hand-signal, but that's only a guess. (I think the quotes after '25' are a simply mistake, and they should be after 'minutes').

Comment: @ColinFine - Interesting!  I don't know whether this is a very specifically US term, but I think a lot of US speakers would understand it.  *The over/under on ___* is a very common sports betting term here, enough so that it's sometimes used more metaphorically to mean "the odds of ___"

Comment: I have no interest in betting and little in sport, so it's possible it is known here. But I notice that all the examples from the Wikipedia article are from sports popular in N America.

Comment: @ColinFine, I'm a native to Southern California and I didn't know what it meant until I looked it up.  But it's well known that President Obama is a sports fan, and I'm sure he makes the occasional wager.

Comment: As you'll see from my answer, I didn't even recognise it as a betting term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In closing his speech at the opening of the Museum of African American History, President Obama made a slight jab at former President GW Bush

> It is a monument no less than the others on this mall, to the deep and abiding love for this country and the ideals upon which it is founded.
>
> For we too are America.
>
> [**So enough talk, President Bush was timing me.**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xCht75HO2SI&t=27m5s)
>   *(laughter)*
>   [**He had the over/under at 25.**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xCht75HO2SI&t=27m5s)
>   *(laughter)*
>
> Let us now open this museum to the world...

"Under/over" is a betting term and President Obama was saying that President GW Bush was predicting President Obama's speech to be around 25 mins.

President Obama was making fun that President GW Bush is a man of fewer words than President Obama.  [President GW Bush's remarks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sLRuyBd9fRQ) were 5 mins, whereas [President Obama's remarks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xCht75HO2SI) were half an hour.

Whether President GW Bush actually made such a prediction is left to conjecture, however a certain fondness seems to exist between the two families

> [As Mr. Obama was wrapping up his speech, he could not resist a gentle poke at his predecessor, who is known for his restlessness, laying odds on the length of his own remarks.](http://www.nytimes.com/2016/09/26/us/politics/for-some-bush-obama-rapport-recalls-a-lost-virtue-political-civility.html?_r=0)
>
> [“Enough talk,” Mr. Obama said. “President Bush was timing me. He had the over/under at 25” minutes.](http://www.nytimes.com/2016/09/26/us/politics/for-some-bush-obama-rapport-recalls-a-lost-virtue-political-civility.html?_r=0)

Answer (score 4):

Here's the reference for those who don't understand the term: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Over%E2%80%93under

Over/under is used, usually in sports betting, to indicate a bet in which you say the score will be over or under a certain value.  I'd want to hear the rest of the comment, but my guess is that Obama is joking that Bush bet Obama would speak for more than 25 minutes, implying that Bush thinks Obama is long-winded, and Obama thinks Bush is impatient.